# How to use a NineGrid background image for UWP Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-10, panel

**One** solution I found is to use an `<Image>` inside a `<Grid>`, as shown [here](https://blog.onedevjob.com/2011/09/21/image-ninegrid-in-winrt/)

**Another** way to add background image to `Panel` is

```
<Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Background.jpg"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Grid.Background>
```

However I haven't found how to make the `ImageBrush` utilize `NineGrid`.

Is the first method the right way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) control has a [NineGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.ninegrid#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_NineGrid) property, but the [ImageBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush) doesn't. If you want to put a image as the Panel's background, the simplest way is putting the Image control on the bottom layer as your first way.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image Source="Assets/image.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" NineGrid="50"/>
    <!--Put your xaml control here-->
</Grid>
```